# Is using filter2 on a 1D signal equivalent to using filtfilt in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, filtering, signal-processing, convolution, digital-filter

Is using [`filter2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter2.html) on a 1D signal equivalent to using [`filtfilt`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/filtfilt.html) in MATLAB, meaning there is zero-phase delay?

Answer (score 1):

No,
`filter2` is 2d implementation of the `filter` function.
It has the same relation of `conv2` to `conv`.

If you need `filtfilt` in 2d you can easily implement it using `filter2` just as easy as you'd implement `filtfilt` using `filter`.